# Can you insert custom CSS as external resource with DOM Element variable in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, css, dom, google-tag-manager

I have my Google Tag Manager tracker installed on a third-party platform and that's my only access to the platform's back-end code.

Is it possible to insert a custom external CSS link in the platform with DOM Element variable in Google Tag Manager to style the page? By "custom external CSS", I mean something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/mystyle.css">
```

that goes in the platform's `<head>`.

Comment: I know that with a CustomHTML tag, I can push a jquery snippet, something like this: $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/mystyle.css">'); .. but how does this affect the styling and loading/rendering of the page? The CustomHTML tags will be added at the bottom of the page and then the jquery code adds the link to the head. Does that help with styling the page?